# Finding a user by email address

Tags: desire2learn

I was looking at the Users API on the D2L API reference site:
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html

And there does not appear to be a way to find a user by email address.

Is there a way to do this with the current API?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch user records from the [`.../users/`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-) route using either the organization-defined ID, or the user login name properties. Additionally, you can fetch the user record for a user [identified by the LMS UserID property](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-%28D2LID-userId%29). You cannot currently easily retrieve a user record based on another property in the user record: you'd need to fetch entire collection of users and then sort through for the record with the email address you're looking for. With most organizations, this is not at all ideal because of the number of users involved.

Generally improvements to the API of this nature are on the development roadmap, however there isn't a specifically deployment plan in place for an enhancement on this particular use-case. That said, enhancements to the routes to search for fundamental data objects (users, org units) are identified as having strong value by clients and that's a primary driver in determining priority for improvements..